# Tag Username along with item into database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I am attempting to tag the username of the current user along with the truck object. How can I do this?

```
[Http Post]
public ActionResult TruckAdd(TruckList truck)
{
    truck.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
    db.truckList.Add(truck);
    db.SaveChanges();


    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have an added by or created by property to hold the username. You can use  *User.Identity.Name* to retrieve the username of the currently logged in user and do something like this:

```
[Http Post]
public ActionResult TruckAdd(TruckList truck)
{
   truck.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
   truck.AddedBy = User.Identity.Name;
   db.truckList.Add(truck);
   db.SaveChanges();


   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Within your action method you will have access to HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, which is the username of the currently logged in user.

Comment: No. So long as your user is authenticated via forms authentication then the property will be available to you without needing to do anything else.